# Replacement for Delay function on Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm making loading screen on my page that will cover the entire screen for about 10 seconds before it fades into the main content which should have loaded during those 10 seconds.

It works but the issue that the `delay` function shows the loading screen for 10 seconds and the main content doesn't preload during that time period. I just fades into the content, then it begins loading.

How can I change the function so instead of just showing the loading screen, it will also load the main content on the page during the 10 second duration.

```
    <script src=‘http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script>
    $(function() {
        $('<div style="height:100%;width:100%;z-index:1000;background-color:blue;position:absolute;”><br><br><br><center><img src="http://bithumor.co/bh-logo.png" height="100" width="100"></center></div>')
        .insertBefore('body')
        .delay(6000)
        .fadeOut(function() {
          $(this).remove(); 
        });
    });
    </script>
```

Comment: I'm confused, isn't this animation played after document loads? What exactly you mean by preloading?

Comment: The animation is played for 10 seconds before it fades into the main content of the page

Answer (score 0):

Use a timeout to delay a portion of the script asynchronously of the rest of the script.

```
$(function() {
    var loading = $('<div style="height:100%;width:100%;z-index:1000;background-color:blue;position:absolute;”><br><br><br><center><img src="http://bithumor.co/bh-logo.png" height="100" width="100"></center></div>');
    loading.insertBefore('body');
    window.setTimeout(function(){
        loading.fadeOut(function() {
            $(this).remove(); 
        });
    },10000); // 10000 milliseconds = 10 seconds
});
```